# The comment section is not divided equally in Pale Moon

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I recently switch from using Firefox to Pale Moon (a FF fork). The comment section is not divided equally

[image]

Comment: I doubt this will be fixed because Pale Moon is not officially supported: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/260841), and isn't really Firefox anymore...

Comment: why is Pale Moon not really Firefox anymore?

Comment: well... if it's a fork, it isn't maintained by Mozilla and it is 'a browser completely built from its own, independently developed source ( that has been forked off from Firefox/Mozilla code)': https://www.palemoon.org/ -- so it claims, itself, that it isn't really Firefox

Comment: ...Are we just talking about the height? That's expected, you don't have voting/flag controls on your own comments.

Comment: @TimStone I open FF again and, huh, it's the same as PM. It's weird that I see it's weird in PM

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your browser. As Tim Stone pointed out in the comments, your own comments do not have the voting controls at the left and thus do not have the minimum height in order to make room for them. So if your own comment is only one line, it won't have the extra height. If you were to visit the page anonymously, none of the one-line comments would have extra height, because anonymous users have no voting controls ever and you wouldn't need the extra room on any of them.